# 3x3:3 for point to point link - how to configure for one antenna?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I have a TP Link WDR 4310, which apparently is 3x3:3. I can see on the board that there are 3 antenna connections, which all connect to separate circuits (i.e. I assume this means the chipset - AR9344 can manage them completely independently? I'm missing understanding of how the chipset chooses what to put on each antenna, or if I can configure this).

I want to use this router to make a point to point link using OpenWRT. What do I need to configure on the router to use only one of the 3 antennas, and a specific 5GHz channel?

Is 3x3:3 capable of putting 3 spatial streams on one antenna (I assume that is not possible, but somehow I'm also missing understanding about the relationship of chains, spatial streams and antennas.)

Thanks for any help here

m

Comment: Why do you want to use only one antenna? This will seriously diminish throughput.

Comment: Because we would have to buy four more longish-range outdoor antennas (two for each end of the link), and our project is not that wealthy.

Answer (score 3):

Think about the antennas this way: You have two ears, and with those two ears you have *directional* hearing - you know what direction a sound comes from, and if there are people talking to the left of you and to the right of you, it's a lot easier to concentrate on and follow just one discussion with two ears. If you want to do that, you don't cut off one ear and just use the other.

Antennas in MIMO work in the same way: There's a phase difference in the radio waves when the signal is received on each antenna, just like there's a phase difference when your two ears receive the sound waves. And vice versa, the router can send out waves with a phase difference on all antennas ("beamforming") to make the signal stronger for the receiver (here the analogy breaks down, you can't do that with your ears).

So you don't need to configure your router to use one antenna. The WLAN chip firmware will use all three antennas to make the best possible connection. Just set up the connection, everything else is automatic.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a "3x3 MIMO" radio, it means you have 3 transmit radio chains and 3 receive radio chains. This is almost always done by having a total of 3 radio chains, each capable of both transmission and reception. Each radio chain needs its own antenna, so it means you also have 3 antennas. But remember that antennas are just passive chunks of metal. More *antennas* isn't what makes MIMO fast, it's the multiple *radio chains* that makes MIMO fast.

Once you have a MIMO system, you can use your extra radio chains for one of two purposes:

1. Send different data streams out each radio chain. These separate data streams are called spatial streams. Therefore "No", you cannot put multiple spatial streams over the same antenna.
2. Send the same data stream out more than one radio chain, but send it slightly out of phase with the additional radio chains, so that the radio waves they send create constructive interference at the intended receiver, to boost the signal strength that reaches the intended receiver. This is called beamforming. If you've ever heard radio engineers talk about using "phased array antennas" to "steer" the signal in one direction without having to physically point the antennas differently, that's just another way of describing beamforming.

Some MIMO radios may have 3 or 4 tx/rx chains, but not be capable of using them all for separate spatial streams (i.e. it can only use its 3rd or 4th chains for beamforming). So you can't assume that "3x3" means "3 spatial streams". That's why we put the number of spatial streams after the colon. "3x3:3" confirms that your 3x3 MIMO radio is indeed capable of 3 spatial streams.

It *is* possible to create MIMO point-to-point links, but I think de-correlating the antennas might be tricky. Multiple spatial streams requires that each of the receive radio chains gets a different view of the signals from the transmit radio chains, and I imagine that might be hard to do if all 3 antennas at each end of the link are up on the same mast. But I could be wrong, this gets beyond my RF knowledge.

If you don't want to try to make a MIMO point-to-point link, you may be able to configure your firmware to force it into 1x1 mode at all times, and then figure out which radio chain is radio 0 (or 1, if they count from 1), and only hook that chain to your antenna.

Comment: Does STBC fall under either of those two modes? // I think at least Ubiquiti implements point-to-point 2x2 MIMO in airMAX by sending differently polarized signals (thus resulting in 2 views), though I lack understanding of this one.